# JS use drawImage(Image,...) in Image.onload in screenshot codes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm reading chrome extension codes for capturing full page screenshot and here is a piece of codes I cannot figure out the logic behind (https://github.com/erichua23/prj/blob/676e98366c6a25c56b2e342a3aecec76ae076391/screenshot/background.js#L63):

```js
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(this.tabId, { format: "png" }, function(img) {
  var blockImg = new Image();
  var canvas = self.canvas;

  if (Capturer.yPos + Capturer.clientHeight >= Capturer.scrollHeight) {
    blockImg.onload = function() {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var y = Capturer.clientHeight - Capturer.scrollHeight % Capturer.clientHeight;
      ctx.drawImage(blockImg, 0, 0, width, height, 0, self.yPos - y, width, height);
      Capturer.postImg();
    };
  } else {
    blockImg.onload = function() {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(blockImg, 0, 0, width, height, 0, Capturer.yPos, width, height);
      Capturer.yPos += Capturer.clientHeight;
      self.scrollPage(self.tabId, 0, Capturer.clientHeight);
    };
  }

  blockImg.src = img;
});
```

Why putting a blank image on the canvas? And how the screenshot is obtained?
Thank You for your time and expertise.

Comment: Where do you see this code is "putting a blank image one the canvas"? What is `Capturer`? What is `self.scrollPage()`? I guess this would also call `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` doesn't it?

Comment: That's where I don't understand.. `Capturer` is defined at line #12 in the link

Comment: The code you shown makes a call to `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` which will execute the third parameter callback by passing it an URI (probably a dataURI) pointing to an image representing the screenshot. This code prepares a HTMLImageElement, so the screenshot can be drawn on an HTMLCanvasElement. To do this, it has to wait the actual Image has loaded, hence it attaches a load event listener to it. If the Capturer has reached the end of its scrolling-box, it will call `postImg` with that last image, otherwise it will trigger `scrollPage`, which I guess will call recursively that code.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you, I understand it know. It creates a canvas and put the screenshot by `blockImg.src = img`，exactly as you said.